# Given an array all element are duplicates except two element find these two elements

Tags: java, xor

I want to solve this problem using `xor` but I have confused in some lines.

I have done this question through `HashMap` but I want to solve this using `xor` method but I couldn't get some lines in the code.
Like why we are using `xor & ~(xor-1)`.

```
 static void FindTwoUnique(int[] input) {
    int xor = input[0];
    for (int i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
        xor = xor^input[i];
    }
            //I am confused here why we are using this
    int setBit = xor& ~(xor-1);
    int first = 0;
    int second = 0;
          //How we are dividing this into two parts
    for (int i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        if((setBit&input[i]) == 0) {
            first = first^input[i];
        }else {
            second = second^input[i];
        }
    }
    System.out.println(first);
    System.out.println(second);
}
```

Comment: One important information you forgot to mention that the array size must be even. So XOR'ing all the duplicates elements produce 0 finally.

Comment: The remaining XOR is just the xor of those two unknown numbers that you want to find. Hope this will help.

Comment: If there are more than two unique values the algorithm stops working. For example `{1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,4,5,6}` input will give you `2, 5` as output.